# Umbraco admin panel slowdown with azure basic database plan and website performs too slow

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, umbraco, umbraco7

I am using Umbraco v7.8.1

I am not bale to fix the slowdown problem with azure basic database plan, website performs too slow.

In my development environment I am using local database server, to setup my website and then I have restored it to azure database to go live.

And I found that Umbraco admin panel is working too slow than development environment.

So I have change Resource Configuration for live database ( from Basic to Standard with 50 DTU and 2 GB memory)

But still azure database performance is too slow.

I have also refer below links, but failed to fix problem.

[Running Umbraco on Azure Web Apps](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Server-Setup/azure-web-apps)

[Tuning performance in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-performance-guidance)

Please help me to fix this problem

Comment: When you perform a "save" in the backoffice does the database actually use 100% DTU? We had a similar issue and it was actually the location of the XML cache and not the database at all.

Answer (score 1):

A Standard Azure SQL database with 50 DTU is also known as the S2 tier. Taken from the **Best practices** chapter of the document you linked to ([Running Umbraco on Azure Web Apps](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Server-Setup/azure-web-apps)):

> The minimum recommended Azure SQL Tier is "S2", **however noticeable performance improvements are seen in higher Tiers**.

So it's probably relatively easy to improve your performance by upping your Azure SQL Database tier.

Comment: Yes, There is also mentioned that we also need to configure **load balancing** Can you help me to configure that 
Because in this doc it given for **IIS** not for **Azure**
Link : [Load Balancing](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Server-Setup/load-balancing/)

Comment: In spite of Umbraco's 50DTU recommendation we run plenty of sites (some very high traffic ones too) on the S0/10DTU tier.

Comment: @JasonElkin Can you please help me to configure and improve performance ?